# undefined is not an object

Tags: json, react-native

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.data.map')
```

**appBodyData**:

```
render(){
  
    let articles =this.props.data.map(function(articleData,index) {
      return (
        <Card>
        <CardItem>
          <Body>
            <Text>
            {articleData.address.city}
            </Text>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
     
      )
    });
    return (
        <Content>
          {articles}
         </Content>
     );
  }
  
**[appBody:][1]**

getData(){
    return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({data:responseJson.array});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    
    
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getData();
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <AppBodyData data={this.state.data}/>
     );
```

}

This error is shown When I am trying run in emulator.
How can i fix this error.
It seems the map function is not able to get data.
react native cli version :50
sdk version:23

Answer (score 0):

Because your fetch is async, at the time of the first render `this.props.data` is undefined.

Additionally, you need to use `this.state.data` since the result of the fetch is setting the state not props

set inital state in constructor first:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }
```

and then change to state

```
let articles =this.state.data.map(function(articleData,index) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting null value due to fetch method it take time to fetch data so render in if condition

```
render(){
    return (
      <Content>
        {this.props.data?this.props.data.map((articleData,index)=>{
          return <Card>
            <CardItem>
              <Body>
                <Text>
                {articleData.address.city}
                </Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>          
          }):null}     
       </Content>
     );
  }
```